# Group by in LINQ on a property in an array

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array for which I want to group the items based on a property. I tried the below code, but it is not grouping correctyly. `MyArray` is the array and `Id` is the property on which I want to do the grouping.

```
var docGroup = (from x in MyArray
                group x by x.Id).Select(grp => new
                                       {
                                           Id = grp.Key,
                                           Results = grp.ToList(),
                                       })
                                .Results
                                .ToList());
```

To keep it simple if I just make it

```
var docGroup = from x in MyArray  group x by x.Id;
```

where Id is a string "123" in the array and MyArray[2] has both the same Id. When I check the docGroup it has two entries and both have the 123 key instead of just one entry with the 123 key.

Here's a very simple example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test[] tArray = new Test[3];
        Test t = new Test() { Id = "123", Val="First" };

        Test t1 = new Test() { Id = "123", Val="Second" };
        Test t2 = new Test() { Id = "1234", Val="Third" };
        tArray[0] = t;
        tArray[1] = t1;
        tArray[2] = t2;

        var g = from x in tArray group x by x.Id;
    }
}

class Test
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Val { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I look at g it has count 2 of which one is the Id 123 and the second is the Id 1234. I am not sure what is going wrong with my array. So this seems to work, but I am not sure what is going on with my array. I'll do some research on it.

Sorry guys, I found the issue. The Id was in a value property in MyArray which I was not using and so it was not grouping correctly. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: How is it "not grouping correctly?" Can you show the input you're using and the expected output?

Comment: What is the expected output, the .Result is a little confusing

Comment: well I expect the docGroup to be of count 1 since MyArray[2] has both the Id 123 in both places and we are grouping on it.

Comment: @user505210 two groups cannot have same key. Can you add debugger screenshot to question?

Comment: Are the IDs really the same, or does one of them have some trailing whitespace or similar?

Comment: Voting to close as "no longer reproducible". Since it appears that you are no longer looking for help with this, consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works as expected.

GroupBy produces an enumerable of [IGrouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb344977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Since you have two distinct keys ("123" and "1234") you will get an enumerable of two elements. These grouping have a uniqe key and they're by themself enumerables.

So

```
g.Where(x => x.Key == "123").ToList();
```

will contain two elements (First, Second) and

```
g.Where(x => x.Key == "1233").ToList();
```

will contain one element (Third).